# Basic MySql Table Design and SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have 3 tables.

```
Projects
----------
projectId PK
```

```
SubProject
----------
projectId PK  
subProjectId PK
```

Basically, all the projects are listed in the Projects table. A project can have sub projects. So for example, if I have the following rows in my table:

```
Projects
----------
1
2
3
```

```
SubProjects
----------
1,2
1,3
```

There are three projects 1,2, and 3. Projects 2 and 3 are sub projects of project 1.

I have two questions. First, should the foreign keys be the projectId in Projects referencing projectId and subProjectId in SubProjects or should the foreign keys be projectId in subProjects referencing projectId in Projects and subProjectId in subProjects referencing projectId in Projects.

It is worth noting that a Project can be a SubProject to more than one Project.

Secondly, how can I get the sub projects of a project with a query. I have been using:

```
Select * from projects p1 Join subProjects sp Join projects p2 
where p1.projectId = sp.subProjectId and sp.subProjectId = p2.projectId;
```

I get the following result:

```
1 , 2
1 , 3
```

I want it to just return

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may a looking for a self-referenetial relationship as detailed in
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
in which case you would just have one projects table which has a foreign_key in it called parent_project_id and when a project is a sub-project, that subproject uses that parent_project_id to indicate it's parent.  The parent doesn't have any reference to the child in it in terms of foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a question. What about the case when a project is a sub project of more than 1 project. For example, if there are three projects 1,2,3. Say 3 is a sub project of 2 and 1. How could this be modeled?

Comment: Having built a system centered on a tree structure, I would also suggest implementing a [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/).  Tastes good and performs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called SQLmaestro you create these codes automatically, I have a lot of time working with it; generates mysql code (tables, concatenations, joints, custom queries, etc).

Here's the link :  http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/maestro/

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, you will want to replace the `*` with the column name that 2,3 fall under. I don't see column names, so I am not sure if it is `sp`, `p1` or `p2`.